# Standard guarantees for aliases of integer types in C/C++? E.g.: Is "unsigned" always equal to "unsigned int"?

Tags: c++, c, types, integer, alias

First question:

- Is "unsigned" always the same as "unsigned int"?
- Is "signed" always the same as "int"?
- Is "short" always the same as "signed short"?
- Is ...

Second question:

If a C/C++ standard specifies answers to above questions, what paragraphs are related to them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, these are guaranteed.  In C++11, see §7.1.6.2[dcl.type.simple]/table 10, which lists all of the simple type specifiers (and combinations thereof) and what they mean.  For example, the table includes the following:

```
unsigned      => unsigned int
unsigned int  => unsigned int

signed        => int
signed int    => int
int           => int
```

C11 has a similar mapping in §6.7.2/2 (it's formatted differently, but otherwise it specifies the same groups of equivalent combinations, at least for all of the types common to C and C++).

Comment: It is worth noting that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are 3 distinct types in C++. In C it is implementation defined wether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @rodrigo, are you implying that in C, they're not three distinct types? (Also, in C++ it is also implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.)

Comment: In both C and C++, `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types.  In both C and C++, it is implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @avakar - Actually, in C they _are_ distinct, but the type identity is not so relevant. If `char` happens to be signed then `char` and `signed char` are practically the same. In C++ type identity _is_ relevant because it relates to many language constructs, such as function overloading or template instantiation: `f(char)`, `f(signed char)` and `f(unsigned char)` are 3 valid different overloads).

Comment: @rodrigo, right, but you can't assign `char *` to `signed char *` in C (at least in C99) can you?

Comment: @avakar: In C you can assign pointers of different types without error. Whether it emits a warning in these cases is compiler dependent. For what is worth, my GCC (4.7.2) does emit such a warning by default, (-Wpointer-sign) even when assigning `char*` to a `signed char*` and `char` being signed.

Comment: @rodrigo: Assigning pointers of different types violates the constraint in C 2018 6.5.16.1 1 (same in C 2011 and C 1999) except that the assignment may add qualifiers and the right operand may be a `void *` (with qualifiers also present on the left operand).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think that 6.5.16.1 describes the syntax of the assignment, not the semantics. That with 6.3.2.3 (7) says "A pointer to an object [...] may be converted to a pointer to a different object [...]", that allows to assign pointers of different types freely. If derefencing that pointer is UB or not is described in 6.5 (7) "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one ofthe following types: ... * a character type". So, if IUIC, you can read a `char` using a pointer to `signed char` and vice versa.

Comment: @rodigo: Syntax is determined purely by lexical rules and grammar. The constraint is semantic; it uses type information that is only developed by interpreting the meaning of the expressions. Yes, you can convert pointers, but that does not mean you can assign them freely. First, the fact that conversions can be performed does not mean they are valid everywhere. You can compel a conversion with a cast. But conversions are not “freely” assign pointers. There are constraints, such as the one labeled “Constraints” in 6.5.16.1. Something that is constrained is not free.

Comment: @rodrigo: And while `char` can be used to read a `signed char` and vice versa, this is not true with other types generally, such as `int` and `unsigned int`. “Freely” assigning pointers to diverse types to each other would result in violations of the aliasing rules.